# jquery find element by name based on input value and assign its id to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have about 9 unordered lists which resemble a color group (red, blue, green etc.). Each color group holds an x amount of list items (light blue, dark blue etc.). When a user clicks a certain list item, it will assign the list item's id (which contains a certain background color) to the previewbox and displays the chosen background color. It also passes the text string of the clicked list item to the input field .numbercheck. I need this text string for further processing.

Example of the HTML markup:

```
<input type="text" class="numbercheck">
<div class="previewbox" id="nocolor"></div>

<div class="color-panels">
  <ul id="blue-panel" class="colorpanel">
    <li id="ral-1000-lightblue" name="1000">RAL 1000</li>
    <li id="ral-1001-darkblue" name="1001">RAL 1001</li>
  </ul>

  <ul id="red-panel" class="colorpanel">
    <li id="ral-2000-red" name="2000">RAL 2000</li>
    <li id="ral-2001-darkred" name="2001">RAL 2001</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What I described above works, the text string is passed to the input field and the correct color is displayed in the preview box. But I also want the user to be able to type in a certain number (i.e. 2000), then look for the list item with the same name (this would be `<li id="ral-2000-red" name="2000">RAL 2000</li>`). If the `<li>` name matches the input value, then the list item's id should be passed to the previewbox like this `<div class="previewbox" id="ral-2000-red"></div>`. If the name doesn't match the input value, then the id should stay `id="nocolor"`.

Note that I already have a working function which extracts the numbers from the input value, so when "ral 1000" or "abc 1000" etc. is entered, it will extract 1000 from the string.

I've been searching the internet for hours, and at this point I have no clue what kind of code to use to accomplish this. I already tried stuff like:

```
var colorname = $('.colorpanel li').attr('id');
var inputval = $('input.numbercheck').val();
if (colorname == inputval){
    $('.previewbox').attr('id',colorname);
}
```

Or:

```
var inputval = $('input.numbercheck').val();
var listitem = $('.colorpanel li[name='inputval']').attr('id');
```

The last example doesn't work for me, it gives me an error which says ")" is missing at the line where `var listitem` is located.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

`$('.colorpanel li[name='inputval']').attr('id');`

with

`$('.colorpanel li[name='+ inputval+ ']').attr('id');`

Answer (score 0):

Since `inputval` is a variable you need to create selector text properly.

```
var inputval = $('input.numbercheck').val();
var listitem = $('.colorpanel li[name='+ inputval + ']').attr('id');
```

Comment: I didn't know it worked that way, thank you for your answer!